# React Native Debugger "Unsupported DevTools backend version"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging, react-devtools, react-native-debugger

When I try to debug my app with React Native Debugger I got that error: "

[error from react native debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TOx0.png)

then I do that instruction. install `react devtool`, and nothin happen.
I think, maybe, I have some error when installing the package, so I run `react devtools` and see that current version 4.23.0

[react-devtools version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmsb9.png)

so anybody have any idea how I can fix that problem?

Answer (score 6):

I "npm install"ed 'react-devtools' and 'react-devtools-core' and set them to the same version

```
   "react-devtools": "~4.14.0",
   "react-devtools-core": "~4.14.0",
```

and re-installed everything by deleting package-lock.json and node_modules

then ran npm install and it worked

I think the problem was those packages not being the same version

Comment: Thank's a lot. I do as you recommended and it's work. I can add plus to you answer, because i don't have enough rating )))

Answer (score 3):

I tried to sync both versions by doing the fresh global and local install.
But after a long time, the local combination and resolutions for the version worked for me.

I added the following in `packege.json` as dev depedencies.

```
  "react-devtools": "~4.24.5",
   "react-devtools-core": "~4.24.5"
```

And

```
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native/react-devtools-core": "4.24.0"
  },
```

Restarted the env, opened `yarn react-devtools`, and then opened dev menu and select inspect options and it got connected to dev tools and I was able to inspect my UI components in devtools.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is seeing this dialog: [image]

**Here is the solution which worked for me on M1 Mac:**
Uninstall the homebrew version of `react-native-debugger` and install the [react-native-debugger_0.11.7.dmg](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases/download/v0.11.7/react-native-debugger_0.11.7.dmg) binary.

More info [here](https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/4bc90775530873fdf8e7ade4a039e579)